# Using INNER JOIN with multiple conditions in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below data and I need to join the two tables and get the results so that it converts PRICE1_VALUE and PRICE2_VALUE to EURO in the single record.

```
SELECT
PRODUCT,
CASE 
        WHEN PRICE1_VALUE ='EURO'
            THEN PRICE1_VALUE
            ELSE [T1.PRICE1_VALUE]*T2.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END AS [PRICE1_VALUE],
CASE
        WHEN PRICE2_VALUE ='EURO'
            THEN PRICE2_VALUE
            ELSE [T1.PRICE2_VALUE]*T2.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END AS [PRICE2_VALUE],
T1.START_DATE
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON      YEAR (T1.START_DATE)= YEAR(T2.START_DATE)
AND     MONTH(T1.START_DATE)= MONTH(T2.START_DATE)
AND     (T1.PRICE1_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
    OR   T1.PRICE2_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
    )
WHERE TO_CODE = 'EURO'
```

With this query its returning two separate records against each record, which I can understand is because of the way I have joined the two tables. *Could you please help understand how I could fix it?*

I understand its this condition causing it to return multiple records.

```
AND     (T1.PRICE1_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
    OR   T1.PRICE2_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
    )
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace the OR with a 2nd join to TABLE2

Comment: Avoid images. Try to put textual data in table format.

Comment: Hi, sorry i tried to copy paste the text directly but it converts it to image automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want with two `left join`s:

```
SELECT PRODUCT,
       (CASE WHEN PRICE1_CURRENCY ='EURO'
             THEN PRICE1_VALUE
              ELSE T1.PRICE1_VALUE * T2_1.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END) AS PRICE1_VALUE,
       (CASE WHEN PRICE2_CURRENCY = 'EURO'
             THEN PRICE2_VALUE
             ELSE T1.PRICE2_VALUE * T2_2.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END ) AS PRICE2_VALUE
       T1.START_DATE
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 T2_1
     ON YEAR(T1.START_DATE) = YEAR(T2_1.START_DATE) AND
        MONTH(T1.START_DATE) = MONTH(T2_1.START_DATE) AND
        T1.PRICE1_CURRENCY = T2_1.FROM_CODE LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 T2_2
     ON YEAR(T1.START_DATE) = YEAR(T2_2.START_DATE) AND
        MONTH(T1.START_DATE) = MONTH(T2_2.START_DATE) AND
        T1.PRICE2_CURRENCY = T2_2.FROM_CODE 
WHERE T2_1.FROM_CODE IS NOT NULL OR T2_2.FROM_CODE IS NOT NULL;
```

Note:  Do not overuse square braces.  Your use looked incorrect in your code and was unnecessary.

Comment: So you think OP wants the data "pivoted". Interesting approach.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis: The original data is "pivoted", both `PRICE1_VALUE` & `PRICE1_VALUE` columns exist :-)

Answer (score 2):

You must replace the OR-join with another join to TABLE2:

```
SELECT
PRODUCT,
CASE 
        WHEN PRICE1_VALUE ='EURO'
            THEN PRICE1_VALUE
            ELSE [T1.PRICE1_VALUE]*T2.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END AS [PRICE1_VALUE],
CASE
        WHEN PRICE2_VALUE ='EURO'
            THEN PRICE2_VALUE
            ELSE [T1.PRICE2_VALUE]*T3.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END AS [PRICE2_VALUE],
T1.START_DATE
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 -- maybe LEFT JOIN
ON      YEAR (T1.START_DATE)= YEAR(T2.START_DATE)
AND     MONTH(T1.START_DATE)= MONTH(T2.START_DATE)
AND     T1.PRICE1_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T3 -- maybe LEFT JOIN
ON      YEAR (T1.START_DATE)= YEAR(T3.START_DATE)
AND     MONTH(T1.START_DATE)= MONTH(T3.START_DATE)
AND     T1.PRICE2_CURRENCY= T3.FROM_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your query is doing what you want it to.

The specific answer to your question - "Why do I get two results?" is that the OR clause matches a the "1 to 1" conversion row in your table:

OR   T1.PRICE2_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE

A better version of your query would be:

```
SELECT
PRODUCT,
T1.PRICE1_VALUE *P1_CONVERSION_RATE.EXCHANGE_VALUE AS [PRICE1_VALUE],
T1.PRICE2_VALUE *P2_CONVERSION_RATE.EXCHANGE_VALUE AS [PRICE2_VALUE],
T1.START_DATE
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 P1_CONVERSION_RATE
ON      YEAR (T1.START_DATE)= YEAR(T2.START_DATE)
AND     MONTH(T1.START_DATE)= MONTH(T2.START_DATE)
AND     T1.PRICE1_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
INNER JOIN TABLE2 P2_CONVERSION_RATE
ON      YEAR (T1.START_DATE)= YEAR(T2.START_DATE)
AND     MONTH(T1.START_DATE)= MONTH(T2.START_DATE)
AND     T1.PRICE2_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want EURO as a result only, you can just add in the end:

```
where T2.TO_CODE='EURO'
```

However, if you want to see both prices for each product, stick to Gordon's solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do using distinct

```
SELECT  distinct
PRODUCT,
CASE 
        WHEN PRICE1_VALUE ='EURO'
            THEN PRICE1_VALUE
            ELSE [T1.PRICE1_VALUE]*T2.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END AS [PRICE1_VALUE],
CASE
        WHEN PRICE2_VALUE ='EURO'
            THEN PRICE2_VALUE
            ELSE [T1.PRICE2_VALUE]*T2.EXCHANGE_VALUE
        END AS [PRICE2_VALUE],
T1.START_DATE
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON      YEAR (T1.START_DATE)= YEAR(T2.START_DATE)
AND     MONTH(T1.START_DATE)= MONTH(T2.START_DATE)
AND     (T1.PRICE1_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
    OR   T1.PRICE2_CURRENCY= T2.FROM_CODE
    )
```

Comment: Hi, it returns the same result with distinct because the EXCHANGE_VALUE is different in each case.

Comment: are u selecting exchange_value in select?

Comment: no but since it does a multiplication by it in the result based on the currency, the end value is different.